# How can I create a shortcut on the desktop for Mac

Tags: mac, macbook

I am using a MacBook Pro running Mac OS X 10.5. I am new to this development environment, and previously worked on Windows.

How can I create a shortcut for applications or documents on the desktop? Just like the "Show on desktop" feature from Windows?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The shortcut in Windows is called Alias in MacOS.

Creating an alias

From http://kb.iu.edu/data/achy.html

You have several options for creating an alias:

- Drag and drop: Click the item you wish to alias and hold down the mouse button. Then, while holding down the `Command` and `Option` keys, drag the item to where you want the alias to appear. Instead of moving the original item, this will create an alias at the new location.
- Contextual menus: Hold down the `Ctrl` key and click the item you wish to alias. From the contextual menu, select **Make Alias**. The new alias will appear next to the original.
- Keystroke: Select the item you wish to alias, and press `Command-l` (the lowercase L). The new alias will appear next to its original.
- File menu: Select the item, and then from the File menu, select **Make Alias**. A new alias icon will appear next to the original.

Once you've created an alias, you can move it to a more convenient location, and then rename it or give it a new icon as you wish.